# Не могу разобраться в последовательности

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 2 функции, одна показывает блок, вторая прячет.
Та что показывает :

```
    function openBlock(block)
    {
        var container = $("#" + block.id);
        container.addClass('zoomIn').show();
    }
```

Та что прячет :

```
    function closeBlock(block)
    {
        var container = $("#" + block.id);  
        container.removeClass("zoomIn").addClass('zoomOut').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
            container.removeClass("zoomOut").hide();
        });                         
    }
```

При первом открытие блока это работает хорошо, но когда после первого закрытия я открываю блок снова. через секунду после открытия он закроется, еще раз открою будет норм, закрою, ситуация повторится. Я только начал знакомство с `js` и `jq`. Я не конца понимаю как работает последовательность через символ "." и в каких случаях можно прописывать `function` в последовательности. Прошу помочь разобраться.

```js
function closeBlock(block)
{
   var container = $(block);  
    container.removeClass("zoomIn").addClass('zoomOut').on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
       container.removeClass("zoomOut").hide();
    });                         
}

function openBlock(block)
{
    var container = $(block);
    container.addClass('zoomIn').show();
}
```

```css
.cityBlock{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="button" value="Открыть" class="btnClose" id="btnCloseField" onclick="openBlock(cityBlock);">
<div class="animated pull-left cityBlock" id="cityBlock">
    <input type="button" class="btnClose" value="Закрыть" id="btnCloseField" onclick="closeBlock(cityBlock);">
    <div class="blockHead">
        <span>Вся Украина</span>
        <hr>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span onclick="choseCity(this);">
                    Киев
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `.one` использовать `.on`. Вы аттачите обработчик события, которые выполнится один раз. Скорее всего в этом и есть проблема.

Comment: @Klimenkomud стало хуже, теперь не работает со 2 раза, после первой успешной отработки при открытие повторном сразу закрывается, не пойму где связь, при открытии используется только `openBlock` и почему он закрывает сразу после открытия.

Comment: приведите воспроизводимый пример - чтобы можно было посмотреть, как и что работает

Comment: @humster_spb добавил, попробуйте поклацать открыть/закрыть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Методом научного тыка выяснилось, что hide() здесь лишний (видимо, zoomOut и так скрывает блок):

```js
function openBlock(block)
{
    var container = $(block);
    container.removeClass('zoomOut').addClass('zoomIn').show();
}

function closeBlock(block)
{
   var container = $(block);
   container.removeClass("zoomIn").addClass("zoomOut");          
}

var open = document.getElementById('btnOpenField');
var close = document.getElementById('btnCloseField');
var span = document.getElementById('spanCloseField');

open.onclick = function() {
   openBlock(cityBlock);
}
close.onclick = function() {
   closeBlock(cityBlock);
}
span.onclick = function() {
   closeBlock(cityBlock);
}
```

```css
.cityBlock{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="button" value="Открыть" class="btnClose" id="btnOpenField">

<div class="animated pull-left cityBlock" id="cityBlock">
    <input type="button" class="btnClose" value="Закрыть" id="btnCloseField">
    <div class="blockHead">
        <span>Вся Украина</span>
        <hr>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span id="spanCloseField">
                    Киев
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А вот как вы повесили события, это так правильно?

Comment: @Winteriscoming, ну, можно, наверное, как-то заморочиться и оптимизировать всё до одной клик-функции, куда будут просто параметры передаваться, но сам принцип должен быть именно такой. вызовы функции из html - это плохая практика (например, Ваш код в песочнице jsfiddle не работает, потому что функции вызываются раньше, чем определяются)

Comment: У меня почему то не работает такой подход. Блок должен открыватся по фокусу на поле и я сделал вот так 
`var open = document.getElementById('setCity');`
            `open.onfocus = function() {
                alarm("its work!");
            }`
Не работает

Comment: @Winteriscoming, а что такое "alarm"? :)) Наверное, alert?

Comment: не важно все равно не пашет. Обвернул все в window.onload тогда заработало.

Comment: @Winteriscoming, да не, window.onload не при чём. Опять же, если бы Вы привели воспроизводимый пример, я бы указал, в чём именно проблема.

Comment: @Winteriscoming, и, кстати, если Вы сделаете alert на фокус, то Вы никогда этот алерт не закроете - будет что-то типа бесконечного цикла. Так что так лучше не делать (вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/ht4wetqx/)

Comment: на jsfiddle работает без `window.onload` у меня нет. Вот такое у меня локально не работает
`<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var openCityBlock = document.getElementById('setCity');

            openCityBlock.onfocus = function() {
                alert("Its work");
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
            <input type="text" id="setCity" value="" />
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: @Winteriscoming, а, ну так конечно - у Вас скрипт отрабатывает раньше , чем появляются элементы, с которыми он должен работать. Скрипт надо ПОСЛЕ разметки элементов прописывать. Ну или, да, - window.onload: он заставляет скрипт ждать, пока html загрузится. Но это лишнее - достаточно просто в правильном месте вставить скрипт.